# text on 3d curve

Tags: modifiers, bezier-curves, text-object

I have a text on 3D curve (using modifier). When I render the image, there are some unwanted lines on text.
I have found a solution for this: http://vimeo.com/19894131 -> converting text to mesh.

I would like to know, if any other method exists where I don not have to convent the text, because this way I lose the opportunity of further editing.

[image: error on text]

File available [here](http://www.4shared.com/file/u1x4Rmpcba/ferde.html) and [here (PasteAll mirror)](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/29970). I'm using Cycles render engine.

Comment: I'm guessing this is caused by the way the text objects are triangulated, however that wouldn't explain why converting it to a mesh would fix it.. I couldn't reproduce the issue in your image. Could you upload your .blend or some screenshots? (Also, are you using BI or Cycles?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding a Decimate Modifier to the text before the Curve Modifier, with the default Decimate values with Planar selected, seems to improve the situation to my eye. But granted, at the expense of some other (perhaps acceptable or even likeable) deformation. Here is a before and after, with modifier values shown:

[image: Original ferde.blend]

[image: Modified ferde.blend]

Adding Triangulate and EdgeSplit modifiers after Decimate may improve smoothness a bit:
[image: Detail of modifier stack]
[image: Final output]

Comment: That's works great!

Comment: Do you know any workaround for smooth/nice edges of letter G?

Comment: Adding a Triangulate modifier followed by an EdgeSplit modifier AFTER the Decimate modifier indicated in the answer improves smoothness a bit. See edit to answer for illustration.

Comment: much more nicer than before, but the lover (left) part (of G letter) is still dis-formed.

Answer (score 0):

If the distortion of the text causes filling artifacts, you can enable **Fill Deformed**, This will evaluate the distorted geometry when filling.

However its hard to tell in your case if this will give an improvement.

Comment: this setting don't work